# Error illegal start of expression en public static void main(String args[])

Tags: java, login

Ante todo lo siento, pero soy nuevo por aquí y no se como funciona muy bien, nuevo en overflow y nuevo programando, resulta que estoy creando un inicio de sesión con una barra de progreso del 0% al 100% , pero en el final del código, en **public static void main(String args[])** me sale un error que pone **illegal start of expression** he buscado y no tengo ni idea , antes no me salia ese error y ahora si, muchas gracias de antemano.

tampoco entiendo muy bien porque algunos methods no los reconoce, por ejemplo el metodo **tiempo.stop()**, lo tuve que cambiar por **tiempo.cancel()** que ni si quiera se si esta bien, pero se me quito el error.

---

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

//KeyEvent para crear un evento al pulsar una tecla.

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Timer;


public class Inicio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//creando un contador para la barra de progreso.
private Timer tiempo;
int cont;
public final static int TWO_SECOND = 5;



/**
 * Creates new form Inicio
 */
public Inicio() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void inicioSesion(){
    String usuario = txtusuario.getText();
    String contra = String.valueOf(txtcontra.getPassword());

    if(usuario.equals("Bilnus")&& contra.compareTo("12345")==0){

        cont=-1;
        barra.setValue(0);
        barra.setStringPainted(true);
        tiempo=new Timer(String.valueOf(TWO_SECOND),true);
        activar();

    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"¿No te sabes tus credenciales inútil?");
    }

}
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    txtusuario = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtcontra = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    barra = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(102, 102, 102));
    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    txtusuario.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtusuarioActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(txtusuario, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(241, 54, 157, -1));

    jLabel1.setText("Usuario");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(41, 54, 190, 20));

    txtcontra.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtcontraActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    txtcontra.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            txtcontraKeyPressed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(txtcontra, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(240, 90, 160, -1));

    jLabel2.setText("Contraseña");
    jPanel1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(40, 90, 200, 20));

    jButton1.setText("Iniciar");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel1.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(320, 130, -1, -1));
    jPanel1.add(barra, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 130, 280, 20));

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 450, 410));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void txtcontraActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void txtusuarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
inicioSesion();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void txtcontraKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(evt.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        inicioSesion();

    }
}                                    

private void activar() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

// implementar el progreso de nuestra barra de progreso.
class timerListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       cont++;
       barra.setValue(cont); //seleccionamos el valor contador a la barra.
       if(cont == 100){
       tiempo.cancel();
       esconder();

       Menu_Principal menu = new Menu_Principal();
       menu.setVisible(true);
       setVisible(false); // se sustituye por this.dispose.
        //this.dispose(); //para que se cierre la ventana actual de la contraseña y usuario. quie aqui ya no hace falta
       }
    }

}

//cuando llegue la barra a 100 que desaparezca
public void esconder(){this.setVisible(false);

//activar la barra de progreso


// public void activar(){tiempo.start();}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Inicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Inicio().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JProgressBar barra;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField txtcontra;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtusuario;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Te falta la llave de cierre en el método `esconder`. Te falta el tipo de retorno del método `inicio` que probablemente sea `void`.

Comment: muchas gracias, se me paso la llave de esconder, ahora solucione el error del main, aunque me sale otro en donde pone ```public void activar(){tiempo.start();}``` ,que en el codigo esta puesto en comentario,  me dice que el method activar() ya esta definida dentro de la clase inicio , pero no lo entiendo.

Comment: ejecuto el programa y se queda en 0% la barra de progreso y no me lanza a la pagina principal del programa